# gRPC protocol buffer generating invalid client stub (Javascript)

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc, rpc, grpc-web

I am attempting to send requests from my React client to my backend directly via the browser with an envoy proxy. Along the way I have come to a standstill involving an issue with my client stub not containing a function implementation stated in my protocol buffer after compilation.

I have generated client stubs for my React client with the command listed:

`protoc -I=. video_chunk.proto --js_out=import_style=commonjs:. --grpc-web_out=import_style=commonjs,mode=grpcwebtext:.`

Protocol Buffer: video_chunk.proto

```
syntax = "proto3";

package video_chunk;

// Message for sending chunks of the file
message ChunkRequest {
    bytes content = 1;    // chunk data
    string filename = 2;  // original filename
}

// Response message
message ChunkResponse {
    int32 pushup_count = 1;
    string message = 2;
    string status = 3;
}

service UploadService {
    rpc Upload(stream ChunkRequest) returns (ChunkResponse);
}
```

However my generated client stub looks like this (missing upload()):

video_chunk_grpc_web_pb.js

```
/**
 * @fileoverview gRPC-Web generated client stub for video_chunk
 * @enhanceable
 * @public
 */

// Code generated by protoc-gen-grpc-web. DO NOT EDIT.
// versions:
//  protoc-gen-grpc-web v1.4.2
//  protoc              v4.24.3
// source: video_chunk.proto


/* eslint-disable */
// @ts-nocheck



const grpc = {};
grpc.web = require('grpc-web');

const proto = {};
proto.video_chunk = require('./video_chunk_pb.js');

/**
 * @param {string} hostname
 * @param {?Object} credentials
 * @param {?grpc.web.ClientOptions} options
 * @constructor
 * @struct
 * @final
 */
proto.video_chunk.UploadServiceClient =
    function(hostname, credentials, options) {
  if (!options) options = {};
  options.format = 'text';

  /**
   * @private @const {!grpc.web.GrpcWebClientBase} The client
   */
  this.client_ = new grpc.web.GrpcWebClientBase(options);

  /**
   * @private @const {string} The hostname
   */
  this.hostname_ = hostname.replace(/\/+$/, '');

};


/**
 * @param {string} hostname
 * @param {?Object} credentials
 * @param {?grpc.web.ClientOptions} options
 * @constructor
 * @struct
 * @final
 */
proto.video_chunk.UploadServicePromiseClient =
    function(hostname, credentials, options) {
  if (!options) options = {};
  options.format = 'text';

  /**
   * @private @const {!grpc.web.GrpcWebClientBase} The client
   */
  this.client_ = new grpc.web.GrpcWebClientBase(options);

  /**
   * @private @const {string} The hostname
   */
  this.hostname_ = hostname.replace(/\/+$/, '');

};


module.exports = proto.video_chunk;
```

video_chunk_pb.js

```
// source: video_chunk.proto
/**
 * @fileoverview
 * @enhanceable
 * @suppress {missingRequire} reports error on implicit type usages.
 * @suppress {messageConventions} JS Compiler reports an error if a variable or
 *     field starts with 'MSG_' and isn't a translatable message.
 * @public
 */
// GENERATED CODE -- DO NOT EDIT!
/* eslint-disable */
// @ts-nocheck

var jspb = require('google-protobuf');
var goog = jspb;
var global =
    (typeof globalThis !== 'undefined' && globalThis) ||
    (typeof window !== 'undefined' && window) ||
    (typeof global !== 'undefined' && global) ||
    (typeof self !== 'undefined' && self) ||
    (function () { return this; }).call(null) ||
    Function('return this')();

goog.exportSymbol('proto.video_chunk.ChunkRequest', null, global);
goog.exportSymbol('proto.video_chunk.ChunkResponse', null, global);
/**
 * Generated by JsPbCodeGenerator.
 * @param {Array=} opt_data Optional initial data array, typically from a
 * server response, or constructed directly in Javascript. The array is used
 * in place and becomes part of the constructed object. It is not cloned.
 * If no data is provided, the constructed object will be empty, but still
 * valid.
 * @extends {jspb.Message}
 * @constructor
 */
proto.video_chunk.ChunkRequest = function(opt_data) {
  jspb.Message.initialize(this, opt_data, 0, -1, null, null);
};
goog.inherits(proto.video_chunk.ChunkRequest, jspb.Message);
if (goog.DEBUG && !COMPILED) {
  /**
   * @public
   * @override
   */
  proto.video_chunk.ChunkRequest.displayName = 'proto.video_chunk.ChunkRequest';
}
/**
 * Generated by JsPbCodeGenerator.
 * @param {Array=} opt_data Optional initial data array, typically from a
 * server response, or constructed directly in Javascript. The array is used
 * in place and becomes part of the constructed object. It is not cloned.
 * If no data is provided, the constructed object will be empty, but still
 * valid.
 * @extends {jspb.Message}
 * @constructor
 */
proto.video_chunk.ChunkResponse = function(opt_data) {
  jspb.Message.initialize(this, opt_data, 0, -1, null, null);
};
goog.inherits(proto.video_chunk.ChunkResponse, jspb.Message);
if (goog.DEBUG && !COMPILED) {
  /**
   * @public
   * @override
   */
  proto.video_chunk.ChunkResponse.displayName = 'proto.video_chunk.ChunkResponse';
}



if (jspb.Message.GENERATE_TO_OBJECT) {
/**
 * Creates an object representation of this proto.
 * Field names that are reserved in JavaScript and will be renamed to pb_name.
 * Optional fields that are not set will be set to undefined.
 * To access a reserved field use, foo.pb_<name>, eg, foo.pb_default.
 * For the list of reserved names please see:
 *     net/proto2/compiler/js/internal/generator.cc#kKeyword.
 * @param {boolean=} opt_includeInstance Deprecated. whether to include the
 *     JSPB instance for transitional soy proto support:
 *     http://goto/soy-param-migration
 * @return {!Object}
 */
proto.video_chunk.ChunkRequest.prototype.toObject = function(opt_includeInstance) {
  return proto.video_chunk.ChunkRequest.toObject(opt_includeInstance, this);
};


/**
 * Static version of the {@see toObject} method.
 * @param {boolean|undefined} includeInstance Deprecated. Whether to include
 *     the JSPB instance for transitional soy proto support:
 *     http://goto/soy-param-migration
 * @param {!proto.video_chunk.ChunkRequest} msg The msg instance to transform.
 * @return {!Object}
 * @suppress {unusedLocalVariables} f is only used for nested messages
 */
proto.video_chunk.ChunkRequest.toObject = function(includeInstance, msg) {
  var f, obj = {
    content: msg.getContent_asB64(),
    filename: jspb.Message.getFieldWithDefault(msg, 2, "")
  };

  if (includeInstance) {
    obj.$jspbMessageInstance = msg;
  }
  return obj;
};
}


/**
 * Deserializes binary data (in protobuf wire format).
 * @param {jspb.ByteSource} bytes The bytes to deserialize.
 * @return {!proto.video_chunk.ChunkRequest}
 */
proto.video_chunk.ChunkRequest.deserializeBinary = function(bytes) {
  var reader = new jspb.BinaryReader(bytes);
  var msg = new proto.video_chunk.ChunkRequest;
  return proto.video_chunk.ChunkRequest.deserializeBinaryFromReader(msg, reader);
};


/**
 * Deserializes binary data (in protobuf wire format) from the
 * given reader into the given message object.
 * @param {!proto.video_chunk.ChunkRequest} msg The message object to deserialize into.
 * @param {!jspb.BinaryReader} reader The BinaryReader to use.
 * @return {!proto.video_chunk.ChunkRequest}
 */
proto.video_chunk.ChunkRequest.deserializeBinaryFromReader = function(msg, reader) {
  while (reader.nextField()) {
    if (reader.isEndGroup()) {
      break;
    }
    var field = reader.getFieldNumber();
    switch (field) {
    case 1:
      var value = /** @type {!Uint8Array} */ (reader.readBytes());
      msg.setContent(value);
      break;
    case 2:
      var value = /** @type {string} */ (reader.readString());
      msg.setFilename(value);
      break;
    default:
      reader.skipField();
      break;
    }
  }
  return msg;
};


/**
 * Serializes the message to binary data (in protobuf wire format).
 * @return {!Uint8Array}
 */
proto.video_chunk.ChunkRequest.prototype.serializeBinary = function() {
  var writer = new jspb.BinaryWriter();
  proto.video_chunk.ChunkRequest.serializeBinaryToWriter(this, writer);
  return writer.getResultBuffer();
};


/**
 * Serializes the given message to binary data (in protobuf wire
 * format), writing to the given BinaryWriter.
 * @param {!proto.video_chunk.ChunkRequest} message
 * @param {!jspb.BinaryWriter} writer
 * @suppress {unusedLocalVariables} f is only used for nested messages
 */
proto.video_chunk.ChunkRequest.serializeBinaryToWriter = function(message, writer) {
  var f = undefined;
  f = message.getContent_asU8();
  if (f.length > 0) {
    writer.writeBytes(
      1,
      f
    );
  }
  f = message.getFilename();
  if (f.length > 0) {
    writer.writeString(
      2,
      f
    );
  }
};


/**
 * optional bytes content = 1;
 * @return {string}
 */
proto.video_chunk.ChunkRequest.prototype.getContent = function() {
  return /** @type {string} */ (jspb.Message.getFieldWithDefault(this, 1, ""));
};


/**
 * optional bytes content = 1;
 * This is a type-conversion wrapper around `getContent()`
 * @return {string}
 */
proto.video_chunk.ChunkRequest.prototype.getContent_asB64 = function() {
  return /** @type {string} */ (jspb.Message.bytesAsB64(
      this.getContent()));
};


/**
 * optional bytes content = 1;
 * Note that Uint8Array is not supported on all browsers.
 * @see http://caniuse.com/Uint8Array
 * This is a type-conversion wrapper around `getContent()`
 * @return {!Uint8Array}
 */
proto.video_chunk.ChunkRequest.prototype.getContent_asU8 = function() {
  return /** @type {!Uint8Array} */ (jspb.Message.bytesAsU8(
      this.getContent()));
};


/**
 * @param {!(string|Uint8Array)} value
 * @return {!proto.video_chunk.ChunkRequest} returns this
 */
proto.video_chunk.ChunkRequest.prototype.setContent = function(value) {
  return jspb.Message.setProto3BytesField(this, 1, value);
};


/**
 * optional string filename = 2;
 * @return {string}
 */
proto.video_chunk.ChunkRequest.prototype.getFilename = function() {
  return /** @type {string} */ (jspb.Message.getFieldWithDefault(this, 2, ""));
};


/**
 * @param {string} value
 * @return {!proto.video_chunk.ChunkRequest} returns this
 */
proto.video_chunk.ChunkRequest.prototype.setFilename = function(value) {
  return jspb.Message.setProto3StringField(this, 2, value);
};





if (jspb.Message.GENERATE_TO_OBJECT) {
/**
 * Creates an object representation of this proto.
 * Field names that are reserved in JavaScript and will be renamed to pb_name.
 * Optional fields that are not set will be set to undefined.
 * To access a reserved field use, foo.pb_<name>, eg, foo.pb_default.
 * For the list of reserved names please see:
 *     net/proto2/compiler/js/internal/generator.cc#kKeyword.
 * @param {boolean=} opt_includeInstance Deprecated. whether to include the
 *     JSPB instance for transitional soy proto support:
 *     http://goto/soy-param-migration
 * @return {!Object}
 */
proto.video_chunk.ChunkResponse.prototype.toObject = function(opt_includeInstance) {
  return proto.video_chunk.ChunkResponse.toObject(opt_includeInstance, this);
};


/**
 * Static version of the {@see toObject} method.
 * @param {boolean|undefined} includeInstance Deprecated. Whether to include
 *     the JSPB instance for transitional soy proto support:
 *     http://goto/soy-param-migration
 * @param {!proto.video_chunk.ChunkResponse} msg The msg instance to transform.
 * @return {!Object}
 * @suppress {unusedLocalVariables} f is only used for nested messages
 */
proto.video_chunk.ChunkResponse.toObject = function(includeInstance, msg) {
  var f, obj = {
    pushupCount: jspb.Message.getFieldWithDefault(msg, 1, 0),
    message: jspb.Message.getFieldWithDefault(msg, 2, ""),
    status: jspb.Message.getFieldWithDefault(msg, 3, "")
  };

  if (includeInstance) {
    obj.$jspbMessageInstance = msg;
  }
  return obj;
};
}


/**
 * Deserializes binary data (in protobuf wire format).
 * @param {jspb.ByteSource} bytes The bytes to deserialize.
 * @return {!proto.video_chunk.ChunkResponse}
 */
proto.video_chunk.ChunkResponse.deserializeBinary = function(bytes) {
  var reader = new jspb.BinaryReader(bytes);
  var msg = new proto.video_chunk.ChunkResponse;
  return proto.video_chunk.ChunkResponse.deserializeBinaryFromReader(msg, reader);
};


/**
 * Deserializes binary data (in protobuf wire format) from the
 * given reader into the given message object.
 * @param {!proto.video_chunk.ChunkResponse} msg The message object to deserialize into.
 * @param {!jspb.BinaryReader} reader The BinaryReader to use.
 * @return {!proto.video_chunk.ChunkResponse}
 */
proto.video_chunk.ChunkResponse.deserializeBinaryFromReader = function(msg, reader) {
  while (reader.nextField()) {
    if (reader.isEndGroup()) {
      break;
    }
    var field = reader.getFieldNumber();
    switch (field) {
    case 1:
      var value = /** @type {number} */ (reader.readInt32());
      msg.setPushupCount(value);
      break;
    case 2:
      var value = /** @type {string} */ (reader.readString());
      msg.setMessage(value);
      break;
    case 3:
      var value = /** @type {string} */ (reader.readString());
      msg.setStatus(value);
      break;
    default:
      reader.skipField();
      break;
    }
  }
  return msg;
};


/**
 * Serializes the message to binary data (in protobuf wire format).
 * @return {!Uint8Array}
 */
proto.video_chunk.ChunkResponse.prototype.serializeBinary = function() {
  var writer = new jspb.BinaryWriter();
  proto.video_chunk.ChunkResponse.serializeBinaryToWriter(this, writer);
  return writer.getResultBuffer();
};


/**
 * Serializes the given message to binary data (in protobuf wire
 * format), writing to the given BinaryWriter.
 * @param {!proto.video_chunk.ChunkResponse} message
 * @param {!jspb.BinaryWriter} writer
 * @suppress {unusedLocalVariables} f is only used for nested messages
 */
proto.video_chunk.ChunkResponse.serializeBinaryToWriter = function(message, writer) {
  var f = undefined;
  f = message.getPushupCount();
  if (f !== 0) {
    writer.writeInt32(
      1,
      f
    );
  }
  f = message.getMessage();
  if (f.length > 0) {
    writer.writeString(
      2,
      f
    );
  }
  f = message.getStatus();
  if (f.length > 0) {
    writer.writeString(
      3,
      f
    );
  }
};


/**
 * optional int32 pushup_count = 1;
 * @return {number}
 */
proto.video_chunk.ChunkResponse.prototype.getPushupCount = function() {
  return /** @type {number} */ (jspb.Message.getFieldWithDefault(this, 1, 0));
};


/**
 * @param {number} value
 * @return {!proto.video_chunk.ChunkResponse} returns this
 */
proto.video_chunk.ChunkResponse.prototype.setPushupCount = function(value) {
  return jspb.Message.setProto3IntField(this, 1, value);
};


/**
 * optional string message = 2;
 * @return {string}
 */
proto.video_chunk.ChunkResponse.prototype.getMessage = function() {
  return /** @type {string} */ (jspb.Message.getFieldWithDefault(this, 2, ""));
};


/**
 * @param {string} value
 * @return {!proto.video_chunk.ChunkResponse} returns this
 */
proto.video_chunk.ChunkResponse.prototype.setMessage = function(value) {
  return jspb.Message.setProto3StringField(this, 2, value);
};


/**
 * optional string status = 3;
 * @return {string}
 */
proto.video_chunk.ChunkResponse.prototype.getStatus = function() {
  return /** @type {string} */ (jspb.Message.getFieldWithDefault(this, 3, ""));
};


/**
 * @param {string} value
 * @return {!proto.video_chunk.ChunkResponse} returns this
 */
proto.video_chunk.ChunkResponse.prototype.setStatus = function(value) {
  return jspb.Message.setProto3StringField(this, 3, value);
};


goog.object.extend(exports, proto.video_chunk);
```

As you can see there is an issue here with the absence of the Upload function in the stub. I am very new to using gRPC and am not understanding what is wrong...I am thinking that I am generating the stubs incorrectly. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

From the [grpc-web README](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-web):

> gRPC-web currently supports 2 RPC modes:
>
> - Unary RPCs (example)
> - Server-side Streaming RPCs (example) (NOTE: Only when grpcwebtext mode is used.)
>
> Client-side and Bi-directional streaming is not currently supported (see streaming roadmap).

Your RPC is declared like this:

```
service UploadService {
    rpc Upload(stream ChunkRequest) returns (ChunkResponse);
}
```

That's a client-streaming RPC - therefore not supported by grpc-web.